# How to automatically create nodes according to related content types?

Tags: nodes

I am very new to Drupal. I have a situation where I have 3 content types, say A, B, C.

For each node instance of type A, there should be 3 corresponding nodes instances of type B. And for each instance of type B, there should be 5 corresponding nodes instances of type C. So in total 1 + 3 + 15 = 19 nodes.

Is it possible to automatically create the B and C node instances when the A node is created? And it is automatically possible to delete them if A is deleted? In other words, I would like to create tree-like instances of nodes.

Is this possible in Drupal? Is there a module for this, assuming I am creating the 3 content types A, B and C? Alternative solutions/ideas are welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it using hooks
you can use hook_node_save it will be execute after node A is saving to add a new node B,C after you create A
hook_node_save($node)
{
   if($node->type=="A")
   {
      node_save(B);
      node_save(B);
      node_save(B);
      node_save(C);
      node_save(C);
      node_save(C);
      node_save(C);
   }
}

Answer (score 1):

In order to relate content to each other you could try [Relations](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module. But you'll have to extend it in order to automatically create the linked node and delete them if the master node is deleted. Take a look over the docs of this module.